# count non blank rows based on a condition in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

How to set a filter in two different columns then count the remaining rows in Dax.

```
measure =  CALCULATE (
           COUNTROWS( df )
                  ,df[column1] IN { "col1", "col2", "col2" } 
                 &&df[column2] <> 0
        )
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you're facing and your expected results?

Comment: Error: dax comparison operations do not support comparing values of type integer. Consider using VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.
I would like to filter the data where df[column1] IN { "col1", "col2", "col2" } and count the remaining rows where there is no blank in another column df[column2] <> 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
measure =  CALCULATE (
           COUNTROWS( df )
                  ,df[column1] IN { "col1", "col2", "col2" } 
                 && VALUE(df[column2]) <> 0
        )
```